# How to reorder rows in table view at the run time in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am creating one iPhone app but I have one problem in reordering the row at the run time,
   So can any one give me the source code or method which will used for reordering the row/cell at the run time..(i want to place row/cells on the place of other row /cell)

thanks and Regards,
  Priyanka.

Comment: Do you want to change cells in the edit mode (with the user making changes) or the system will make the changes?

Answer (score 0):

may be this one help you http://www.aboutobjects.com/tutorials.html